# Unable to start my app with a breakpoint in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: angular, debugging, asp.net-web-api

I´m using Visual Studio 2022 Professional. My app is using ASP.NET Core Backend and Angular Frontend. Starting my app in debug mode is no problem, but whenever I want to set a breakpoint before I start the app or whenever I want to set a breakpoint and refresh the browser afterwards, the debugging hangs up. It just goes into an endless browser loading.

Has someone experienced a similar problem and can help me with that?

Comment: I have an exact same scenario (VS 2022, although Enterprise, ASP.NET Core backend and Angular frontend) and got today this same problem - I can't debug my application if there are any breakpoints. Looks like it's Microsoft's fault, because other people seem to have exact same problems too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75742820/enabling-javascript-debugger-in-vs-2022-freezes-application

Comment: I have this issue with no Angular FE, just ASP.NET core MVC project. When the breakpoints are enabled, it doesn't start with debugger. When I disable them, it runs as expected, then I need to enable them. It happens with Chrome and Edge for a week now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enabling javascript debugger in VS 2022 freezes application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75742820/enabling-javascript-debugger-in-vs-2022-freezes-application)