# Enabling javascript debugger in VS 2022 freezes application

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, windows-11, javascript-debugger

I have been searching for an answer for 2 days now so really hope someone can help.

When I try to debug my project the application freezes, nothing happens in the browser it just keeps loading and there are no error messages.

I realized that debugging works if i disable javascript debugging. But when i enable it and set a breakpoint ANYWHERE (it does not matter where) the app freezes.

- My computer did an update to Windows 11 Pro in the beginning of the week.
- I have not made any code changes
- The application runs without errors when javascript debugging is disabled.
- I downloaded my project to another computer that runs on Visual studio 2019 (and an older windows version). Then I can debug with javascript and everything works perfectly.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Didn't pick up on the breakpoint aspect though, so thanks for pointing that bit out.

Comment: Glad to help! Please let me know if you figure it out. @RazorUK84

Comment: I am having the same issue too

Comment: Same issue here, disable the feature and use chrome dev tools as a workaround.

Comment: Try posting it on [Super User](https://superuser.com/)

Comment: @RohitGupta using a debugger (a programming tool) is perfectly on-topic here.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved it this way,
I have investigated a lot and I have not found the way to solve it and in this way I achieved it, I hope it helps everyone.
Reset the javascript configuration and it solved in my case

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: That did not work for me. :(

Comment: In my case it did work, I had to reboot for it to take effect

Comment: I tried the solution as presented... didn't work for me.

Comment: That did not work for me. I had exactly the same problem being described. I have finally fixed by, close VS, delete the .vs folder for the project, open the project again, and all working now

Comment: Updating chrome did the trick for me, thank you for your help though! :) @RazmiMartinez

Answer (score 1):

It seems they have fixed it. If you have Edge Dev installed, this morning a new version has been deployed. Version 112.0.1722.15. After updating it also Edge 111.0.1661.51 (Official Builder) and Chrome 111.0.5563.110 (Official build) started to work again.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to delete the project .vs folder.

I also started having this problem after a windows update

Comment: I keep having to delete the .vs folder after setting one. I have found this:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Launching-Chrome-Debugger-fails-if-break/10305614